# Aclaración sobre la creación de una variable en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy leyendo este fragmento de código de aquí [node-printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer/blob/master/lib/printer.js):

```
var printer_helper = {},
    fs = require("fs"),
    child_process = require("child_process"),
    os = require("os"),
    path = require("path"),
    native_lib_path = path.join(__dirname, '../build/Release/node_printer.node'),
    printer_helper;
```

A simple vista me parece que se esta creando una variable (o es un objeto...) que se llama `printer_helper`. Supongo que dentro de este tiene las variables `child_process`, `os` y `path` que hacen referencia a sus respectivos módulos y son importados con `require`.

`native_lib_path` al parecer guarda el path donde esta ubicado el módulo `node_printer_node`

No se si lo que supuse anteriormente es totalmente correcto y además tengo las siguientes dudas:

1. ¿Para que es la primera llave?
2. ¿Porque se agrega el mismo nombre de la variable al final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A simple vista me parece que se esta creando una variable (o es un objeto...) que se llama `printer_helper`

Correcto. `printer_helper` es una variable que contiene un objeto vacío.

> Supongo que dentro de este tiene las variables child_process, os y path que hacen referencia a sus respectivos módulos y son importados con require.

Sí y no. `fs`, `child_process`, `os` y `path` son variables que se inicializan importando los módulos con `require`. Pero esas variables NO están dentro del objeto en la variable `printer_helper`, son independientes (nota como se separan con una coma).

> `native_lib_path` al parecer guarda el path donde esta ubicado el módulo `node_printer_node`

Correcto.

> No se si lo que supuse anteriormente es totalmente correcto y además tengo las siguientes dudas:
>
> 1. ¿Para que es la primera llave?

La primera llave sirve para indicar que `printer_helper` es un objeto.

> 2. ¿Porque se agrega el mismo nombre de la variable al final?

Esto parece un error casi, porque es innecesario. Como no se le asigna ningún valor, simplemente se mantiene el mismo que tenía antes (`{}`) y no afecta nada. Además, si continúas viendo el código que enlazas, puedes ver que ambas inicializaciones son casi inútiles, porque las siguientes líneas inicializan `printer_helper` a un nuevo valor:

```
if(fs.existsSync(native_lib_path)) {
    printer_helper = require(native_lib_path);
} else {
    printer_helper = require('./node_printer_'+process.platform+'_'+process.arch+'.node');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al hacer

```
var printer_helper = {}
```

Declaras que printer_helper debe contener un nuevo objeto vacío.

Luego hay una coma ',' lo cual indica que estas declarando *otra* variable.

Las siguientes variables no forman parte de `printer_helper`, son independientes. Recuerda la coma.

Por último re declarar `printer_helper` no tiene ningún efecto. Pues JavaScript siempre mueve todas las declaraciones de variables al principio de la función y las unifica si están duplicadas, de forma automática y silenciosa.

Con respecto a

> `native_lib_path` al parecer guarda el path donde esta ubicado el módulo node_printer_node

Correcto

Comment: Disculpa el formato estoy en un móvil 